# How many forks or veriations of ubuntu operating systems are around?

Tags: unity

How many forks or veriations of ubuntu operating systems are around?

[1] https://archive.vn/FVT6R/42737cd768844efd5fe48ade4a616f027e42aed9.webp

Some ubuntu's and linux operating systems, they are laced, have their own desktop enviornments as a full operating system.

Is there a list of how many diffrent ubuntu's is out on the internet?
Or could someone give me a idea of where to find other ubuntu's?

Comment: We do not keep track of the various forks and respins. There is no registry, so there is no authoritative answer.

Comment: This is not complete: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg but you can get the idea :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours for officially supported Ubuntu flavors:

> [image] [Kubuntu](https://www.kubuntu.org/)
>
> Kubuntu offers the KDE Plasma Workspace experience, a good-looking system for home and office use.

> [image] [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/)
>
> Lubuntu is a light, fast, and modern Ubuntu flavor using LXQt as its default desktop environment. Lubuntu used to use LXDE as its default desktop environment.

> [image] [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/)
>
> Ubuntu Budgie provides the Budgie desktop environment which focuses on simplicity and elegance. It provides a traditional desktop metaphor based interface utilising a customisable panel based menu driven system.

> [image] [Ubuntu Kylin](https://www.ubuntukylin.com/downloads/show.php?&lang=en)
>
> The Ubuntu Kylin project is tuned to the needs of Chinese users, providing a thoughtful and elegant Chinese experience out-of-the-box.

> [image] [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)
>
> Ubuntu MATE expresses the simplicity of a classic desktop environment. Ubuntu MATE is the continuation of the GNOME 2 desktop which was Ubuntu’s default desktop until October 2010.

> [image] [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/)
>
> Ubuntu Studio is a multimedia content creation flavor of Ubuntu, aimed at the audio, video and graphic enthusiast or professional.

> [image] [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/)
>
> Xubuntu is an elegant and easy to use operating system. Xubuntu comes with Xfce, which is a stable, light and configurable desktop environment.

---

Other Ubuntu-based distros are at least the following:

- [UbuntuDDE](https://ubuntudde.com/) - uses Deepin Desktop Environment;
- [Ubuntu Cinnamon](https://ubuntucinnamon.org/) - uses Cinnamon desktop;
- [Ubuntu Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/) - uses Unity 7 desktop environment;
- [Ubuntu Web](https://ubuntu-web.org/) - Ubuntu web remix combines the power of Ubuntu & Firefox to give you a powerful, free/libre web OS;
- [UbuntuEd](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-education-ubuntued/17063) - potential replacement for obsolete EduUbuntu;
- [Wasta Linux](https://www.wastalinux.org/) - uses Cinnamon desktop and some useful applications;
- [Li-f-e: Linux for Education](https://cyberorg.wordpress.com/) - uses MATE, specialized in education.

If you want more - use DistroWatch.com and set *Based on* filter to [Ubuntu](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=All&origin=All&basedon=Ubuntu&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&package=All&rolling=All&isosize=All&netinstall=All&language=All&defaultinit=All&status=Active#simple) or [Ubuntu LTS](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=All&origin=All&basedon=Ubuntu+%28LTS%29&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&package=All&rolling=All&isosize=All&netinstall=All&language=All&defaultinit=All&status=Active#simple) there.